# WebSphere MQ Explorer read only rights on queues

Tags: permissions, ibm-mq, access-rights

I am trying to restrict users on queues they could see in the Websphere MQ explorer.

What i do right now is just configure Websphere MQ explorer queues in user systems (without any user creation).

I got to see an online help but i could not understand it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you did a search based on your title then Mr. Google would have given the following 2 links at the top of the search results:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q013740_.htm

https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/02/08/using-websphere-mq-explorer-as-a-read-only-viewer/

It is best if you apply the permissions to a group rather than a principle (user).

Comment: Im a newbie and did read through these articles before posting the question. I'm unable to firstly create a group and secondly, when I configure MQ on soneones system there is nothing as such a group assignment that pops up so it basically gives all the rights to that user. Please help thank you